# Script to get the browser version for user

Tags: linux, apache, bash, shell

I've written a script to get the browser version of users but I need to clean up the output. What the script does is looks at the apache logs for @ and IE8 then emails me the information. The problem I have is the output as when the grep finds a email address and IE8  it gives me the full output - i.e. /page/code/user@foobar.com/home.php whereas the output i'm looking is the just the email address and to only have this information recorded once a day:

Example:

user@foobar IE8

Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setting date and time (x and y and z aren't being used at the moment)
x="$(date +'%d/%b/%Y')"
y="$(date +'%T')"
z="$(date +'%T' | awk 'BEGIN { FS =":"} ; {print $1}')"

#Human readable for email title
emaildate=$(date +"%d%b%Y--Hour--%H")

#Setting date and time for grep and filename
beta="$(date +'%d/%b/%Y:%H')"
sigma="$(date +'%d-%b-%Y-%H')"

#CurrentAccess logs
log='/var/logs/access.log'

#Set saved log location
newlogs=/home/user/Scripts/browser/logs

#Prefrom the grep for the current day
grep @ $log | grep $beta | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $7 }' | sort -u >> $newlogs/broswerusage"$sigma".txt 
mail -s "IE8 usage for $emaildate" user@exmaple.com < $newlogs/broswernusage"$sigma".txt
```

Comment: Recommendations: Run the `date` command only once outputting all the fields, etc., that you need at once and parse them into variables using the `read` command. Use better variable names. The default field separator for AWK is already space and tab, there's usually no need to set it to space. AWK can do `grep`-`grep`'s job. There's no need for the semicolon where you have it in the AWK. It's a good idea to develop the habit of always quoting your variables when they're expanded (move the quotes to the outside of your filename for example). You have a typo ("broswer" instead of "browser").

Comment: Could you provide a couple of proper, unprocessed, entries from the log file? Of course, remove personally identifying information from it.

Comment: Log file example: /home/doc/php/user@example.com_info/area/home.php

Comment: This example contains no `IE8` - where does it in your example `user@foobar IE8` come from?